# Can't Touch to right part of the screen when rotated to Landscape iPhone iPad

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, orientation, landscape

I have an app that supports all of orientations. However when I rotate the device after it launches in portrait mode, I cannot touch to the right part of the screen of the iPad. I guess it is a framing issue (I think I cannot touch to 1024-768px width part of the screen) Also when I try to set the frame of self.view to 
CGRectMake (0,0,1024,768) in didrotate method, self.view lays from almost the center to out of screen at the right.

How to solve this? Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because I forgot to update the frame of a view which is above the view which I would like to touch. Issue is resolved with updating all of the views' frames carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to set the frame of self.view,it will be setted automatically.If you set, it will be wrong.I had the same mistake before.